# Referencing a Class method within several Threads causes autoload circular dependency crash

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, thread-safety, activesupport

The code:

```
threads = []
Thread.abort_on_exception=true
begin   # throw exceptions in threads so we can see them
  threads << Thread.new{@a = MyClass.m1}
  threads << Thread.new{@b = MyClass.m2}
  threads << Thread.new{@c = MyClass.m3}

  threads.each { |thr| thr.join }
rescue Exception => e
  puts "EXCEPTION: #{e.inspect}"
  puts "MESSAGE: #{e.message}"
end
```

The crash:

`.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@req/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:478:in load_missing_constant': Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant MyClass`

After digging a little, it appears that since each Thread is referencing MyClass, it is causing an error with ruby auto-loading. If I add a single line with a reference to `MyClass` before I make the Thread calls, it seems to prevent the error.

My question is, is there a "proper" way to prevent this from happening, or is it some bug in ruby? My understanding was that autoloading was thread-safe, per http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2012/08/eager-loading-for-greater-good/

Comment: Rails 4.1.5, Ruby 2.1.3

Comment: Just commenting because I want to follow this.  :)

Comment: What did you do finally?

Comment: I just added a reference to the class before the Thread calls, as mentioned in the question.  Never revisited the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby used to have a problem with `Threaded` `autoload` and even `require` for that matter. It has been fixed in `ruby 2.0` see this [bug on ruby-lang.org](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/921).

Rails may still have the bug [Circular dependency error with lib classes](Circular dependency error with lib classes)

Any way the fix is to simply require or reference the symbol before throwing it into the thread.

```
require 'myclass'
```

or

```
defined? MyClass
```